# Hiding UIDatePicker when tapped around

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` and I want to hide it when tapping outside the button like dismissing a keyboard, I've tried everything and nothing seems to work.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var BDbtn: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker.isHidden = true
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    BDbtn.setTitle("Pick a date!", for: .normal)
}
@IBAction func dateChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    BDbtn.setTitle(formatter.string(from: datePicker.date), for: .normal)

}
@IBAction func BDpressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if datePicker.isHidden {
        datePicker.isHidden = false
    } else {
        datePicker.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should post what you've attempted along with how you're displaying the date picker.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51344812/edit) your question to include the source code that shows what you have tried so that we can help you.

Comment: Can you post a screen cap of your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added datePicker in Scrollview or in main UIView. You can use UITapGestureRecogniser and add one line code in a tapgesture method:

self.view.endEditing(true)

That's it.

Comment: your welcome @rahafalhelo!! Plz, accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: It is a sperate function,it will fire when you touch the screen,meaning in your view controllers class

Comment: that worked fine thanks to you, I just added ( datePicker.isHidden = true ) to the function, thanks again!